# Slow memory allocation in OSX

Tags: c, macos, mmap

I'm trying to trace down a memory allocation problem I have in OSX.
If I compile and run the following code normally, it will run pretty fast.

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>
#define SIZE 8 * 1024 * 1024

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
    mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, if I compile the same code but linking to some library (i.e.: `clang -o test test.c -lpcre`) it will randomly either run fast (30ms) or really slow (18 seconds).

Notice that I'm not even using the library, just linking. I also noticed that this seems not to happen with any library.

I'm running OSX 10.10.3. Any ideas?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. Running it with `iprofile -timeprofiler` shows that all the time is being spent in `__mmap` (which is called from `mmap`). And checking the result of `mmap` shows the call is always succeeding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a bug in the kernel that others have encountered, too. The code in the kernel to find an unused chunk of address space to allocate uses an inefficient search algorithm.

I suspect the reason it seems to depend on whether you link a library is that the dynamic loader (dyld) has to map such a library and that sometimes gets the kernel's VM housekeeping data into the state that triggers the search inefficiency. The reason it doesn't happen on every run probably has to do with Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR).

I encourage you to file a bug with Apple about this, especially since you have a nice simple test case. (It will probably get closed as a duplicate, since I'm sure you won't be the first person to file it. Still, every new bug report can help isolate it and raises its priority within Apple.)

Comment: Do you have any reference for that _others have encountered, too_?

Comment: For example, in [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/34741/focus=34746) about the implementation of `git`. There are other examples. Just do a net search for "os x slow mmap" or similar.

Comment: I filled the bug. I hope they fix it in a future release! When this kind of things happen to me I try to think it has to be something I'm doing wrong. But in this case, after narrowing down the possibilities, seems like there is no other option than a kernel bug.

Comment: @waj can you post the link to your bug? Just looking to track its status.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require the memory to be initialized, it would be more efficient for you to use malloc() as your usage of mmap() is not only allocating 8 mebibytes of memory for your process but also initializing it.

On OS X, both malloc() and mmap() internally use the **mmap() system call** (syscall number 197 - http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/syscalls.master), which asks the kernel to map virtual memory to physical memory.

Comment: malloc() also has to ask the operating system to allocate pages but it does in bigger chunks. But in my case I always need to allocate big buffers to mmap() should be more efficient. Actually I tried to use malloc() and it always runs very slow. Do you have an example where malloc() outperforms mmap()?

Comment: @waj I just did a bit of research in this regard and on OS X you are correct and I have edited my answer. Both mmap() and malloc() use the mmap() system call internally. I was under the impression that malloc() would use the brk() system call internally which simply changes the size of the data segment but this not correct.

Comment: @waj It does not really make sense for malloc() to return slower than mmap() in that example as malloc() does not initialize the allocated memory. However, the speed of these functions is highly implementation specific.

Comment: thank you for the research. I'm still looking for a good way to allocate these big chunks of memory without preinitiallizing the contents. mmap works really well in Linux but not in OSX.

Comment: I tried to use vm_allocate as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html. But I also had the same issue I describe in the initial question.

Answer (score -4):

Sure. Here's an idea. Everybody and his dog allocates memory by calling malloc. Nobody ever in the history of MacOS X has ever used mmap to allocate memory. With that in mind, make a guess which function has been optimised to the max, and for which one the designers of MacOS X don't care one bit about the speed. Use the one that has been optimised.

Comment: In my case I need the memory pages to be lazily allocated that's why I tried using mmap. I tried with both, and not just guessing. Do you know some way to assign virtual memory space in OSX without allocating the pages until used?

Comment: BTW, even though my use of mmap were incorrect, I still would like to know why it behaves strangely when I link to some libary.

Comment: Here's an idea: `malloc` uses `mmap`, so it shouldn't be any faster than just calling `mmap` directly.